# How can I raise an http 404 from a FileStreamResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Normally I'd `return HttpNotFound()` but my method returns a `FileStreamResult` and I get

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpNotFoundResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult'

When I try to build. Is there an alternative version for file results?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type your action method to return the base *ActionResult* rather than the specific *FileStreamResult*.  Then you can return whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw an HttpException.

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
```